# Sending file via email to MMS for AT&T

Tags: python, email, scripting, mms

One can send messages to an AT&T customer via [10-digit-cell-numer]@txt.att.net from their email client. I tried to send a file to my iPhone using this method (specifically an audio file) to no avail. The message came through but the file attachment was not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can send MMS messages to @mms.att.net

That was easy.

Comment: http://www.wireless.att.com/learn/messaging-internet/messaging/faq.jsp. You can indeed use number@mms.ATT.net